# How can I strip whitespace only elements from an array?

Tags: php, arrays, whitespace

How I can remove all elements of an array that contain just whitespace, *not* whitespace in an element like `"foobar  "` but just empty array elements like `"   "`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) is your friend.

```
$array = array("This", " ", "is", " ", "a", " ", "test.");

$array = preg_grep('/^\s*\z/', $array, PREG_GREP_INVERT);

var_dump($array);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/lgic0KhW).

This will drop all array members of which the string is blank or only consist of whitespace according to `\s` character class (spaces, tabs, and line breaks).

#### Output

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "This"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "is"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [6]=>
  string(5) "test."
}
```

Comment: Nice one. This looks faster than a loop.

Comment: You should provide a valid pattern. And I'm not sure if the one you provided works. Better: `preg_grep('^\s*$', $array, PREG_GREP_INVERT);`

Comment: @sims I'm sure it is still looping internally :)

Comment: TIL about PREG_GREP_INVERT, ha.

Comment: not faster than a loog... just looks nicer... probably about the same speed.

Comment: I'm certain that's not a first. :] But let me also contribute something useful: `/\p{Z}/u` for alternatively detecting ninja whitespace. (probably overkill for OPs case)

Comment: @alex: aaaaand C is generally "faster" than PHP. But only tests will tell.

Answer (score 3):

```
$arr = array("This", " ", "is", " ", "a", " ", "test.");
$result = array();
for($arr as $x) {
     if(!preg_match("/^\s*$/", $x)) $result[] = $x;
}
$arr = $result;
```

Answer (score 3):

This code takes advantage of the callback parameter for [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). It will loop the array, call `trim()` on the value, and remove it if the resulting value evaluates to `false`. (which an empty string will)

`$a = array_filter($a, 'trim');`

Comment: This is cool, but it will also [drop members which are *falsy*](http://codepad.org/UaYxowql) such as `'0'`.

Comment: Yes, that is something to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array('foo','  ','bar ');

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (trim($value) == '') unset($array[$key]);
}
```

Array when dumped then contains:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "bar "
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)($arr as $key=>$value)

{

```
 if($value=" ")

  {
```

[unset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)($arr[$key]);

`/* optional */` [array_values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)($arr);

```
  }

}
```

Comment: yes... I thought I could to this properly this way... only after linking I found out this WYSIWYG editor doesn't support it, But after getting the links I was lazy.