# PHP : How to avoid any white spaces or empty string in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to avoid any empty string in an array or any kind of white space. I'm using the following code:

```
<?php
$str="category 1
      category 2


      category 3

      category 4

      ";
$var = nl2br($str);

echo $var."<br>";
$arr = explode("\n", $var);

var_dump($arr); echo "<br>";
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {

    if(($arr[$i]) != '')
    {
        echo $arr[$i]."</br>";      
    }
}
?>
```

How can I remove the white space or empty string like the 2,3,5 index in the array which don't have needed string.

Comment: Hint: use [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function whenever evaluating empty values. For instance, `if(($arr[$i]) != '')` could be `if(!empty($arr[$i]))`.

Comment: Have you tried the solution to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710174/how-can-i-strip-whitespace-only-elements-from-an-array

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array_filter(array_map('trim',$array));
```

Removes all empty values and removes everywhere spaces before and after content!

Comment: nl2br()  puts an <br> tag after all \n , keep that in mind.  function should called br2nl() instead!!  So if you do this `$arr = explode("\n", $var);` after `$var = nl2br($str);` you may have entrys with only <br> in it!!

Comment: Tip:     print htmlentities(var_export($arr,true));   so you will see the <br> in your array

Comment: You shouldn't necessarily have to use `htmlentities` with the `var_dump` as it will display the entire contents of the variable, including the `<br />`.

Comment: That was the plan. See the <br> stuff on page, to get it right. @the_pete

Comment: I know, just saying that you shouldn't need to use additional processing when the `var_dump` accomplishes the same thing you suggested in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your code was pretty much correct, but as was pointed out, your `nl2br` was adding a `<br>` to the end of each line and thus making this a harder process than it should have been.

```
$str="category 1
category 2


category 3

category 4

";
$arr = explode("\n", $str);
var_dump($arr); echo "<br>";
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
    if(($arr[$i]) != '')
    {
        echo $arr[$i]."</br>";
    }
}
```

I used your old code and just removed the `nl2br` line as well as initial `echo` and from there onward, your code actually accomplishes your goal because the `explode("\n", $str)` is all that you need to split on empty lines and your `if` statement covers any lines that happen to be only whitespace.

Comment: Thanks pete for your kind consideration

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've solved it using the following code. Thanks everyone for you help.

```
<?php
$str="category 1
category 2


category 3

category 4




";
$arr = explode("\n", $str);
var_dump($arr);
$result = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++) {
     if(!preg_match("/^\s*$/", $arr[$i])) $result[] = $arr[$i];
}
$arr = $result;
var_dump($arr);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){

        echo $arr[$i]."</br>";

}?>
```